# How long until calling a question an 'exact-duplicate' becomes inappropriate?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, duplicate-questions

Hi folks,
I asked a question on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695536/getting-started-in-mac-development-no-mac-what-do) that was flagged as being an exact  duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22358/how-can-i-develop-for-iphone-using-a-windows-development-machine) question. I had seen this question in the 'similar questions' field, and felt that since it was a year old, that new developments in the technology-space meant that it was worth asking again. (Aside from the fact i asked about Linux, not Windows)

I'm not condoning copy/paste questions, but just questions around a previously dealt with topic.

What is 'retirement' age of questions, where it becomes useful to ask them again?

Comment: Good question. I think the general consensus is "add new info to the old question" but with one that has been accepted, and with answers with that many upvotes, it's *really* difficult for new info to bubble up to the top.

Comment: I know; I got what i was looking for with that question, but I'm just thinking 'for future reference'. That, and noone likes seeing their questions closed.

Comment: I don't mind seeing my question closed if I'm pointed to the answer.  (I've even had to vote to close my own questions a few times after being shown the original.)  If you get what you're looking for, then the system works.  If none of the answers to the old question had been helpful answers to your new question, then it would need to be reopened.

Comment: If you got what you were looking for, then you *don't need to ask again*. At that point you are not accomplishing anything except adding noise to the site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the one hand, I don't think it's *technically* a duplicate, in that you seem to be interested in ways to do this on your Linux deployment. The fact that it's not really possible is irrelevant. :)

On the other hand, you have plenty of answers there, including one you've selected as the answer. ("Get a Mac Mini.") Additionally, since you do need to be running OSX to run the dev tools for the iPhone OS, the bottom line is that this or hackintosh (the same answers for the Windows question) do fulfill your requirements -- and are pretty much the only way to do so.

I voted to reopen, but am already regretting that vote a mere 5 minutes later. (I haven't had caffeine yet this morning, and didn't really think as deeply before clicking "Reopen" as I did before writing this.) The bottom line is that the **answers are the same** no matter which source OS you use. Yes, the original question is a year old, but the walls around the iPhone OS garden have gotten taller, not shorter. As a result, the original answers all still stand, and your question is essentially a duplicate.

So, generally speaking, you resurrect the old question if the question itself is very close to identical, or if the answers will be the same either way. In the situation, the latter was the case, and thus resurrection of the old question and closure of yours is appropriate.

Comment: Unfortunately I essentially agree and am tempted to delete the question myself, but I was interested in seeing what the community considered 'polite' to re-ask a question.